# Points of inflection necessary condition

Tags: calculus

Consider the function $f(x) = x^{2/3}(6-x)^{1/3}$. The first two derivatives are: $f'(x) = \frac{4-x}{x^{1/3}(6-x)^{2/3}}$ and $f''(x) = \frac{-8}{x^{4/3}(6-x)^{5/3}}$. The point of inflection is at $(6,0)$ since the function changes from concave downward to concave upward at this point. However, according to [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InflectionPoint.html): "A necessary condition for $x$ to be an inflection point is $f''(x)=0$." But clearly for this example $f''(6)$ is not even defined, so how is $f''(x) = 0$ a necessary condition for an inflection point?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can think about it this way, at every point of inflection $f''(x)=0$ or is $undefined$ but the the function $f(x)$ must change from concave upwards to downwards( the sign of $f''(x)$ must change). that being said,  for every $x$ value where $f''(x)=0$ or is $undefined$ are only $possible$ points​ of inflection , you have to check weather the sign of $f''(x)$ changes or not.

In short, if $(c,f(c))$ is a point of inflection then we can say:

1. The sign of $f''(x)$ changes at $x=c$
2. $f''(c)$ is either 0 or undefined

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Wolfram may have said that in reference to the [Second Derivative Test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SecondDerivativeTest.html), which requires $f''$ to be defined at the point in question. Because in general, as @alendahmed pointed out, undefined points of the second derivative can also be inflection points (like they are in your case).

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point#A_necessary_but_not_sufficient_condition) says: "If $x$ is an inflection point for $f$ then the second derivative, $f''(x)$, is equal to zero **if it exists**" (emphasis mine).